# Good Java Formatted Text Field Library

Tags: java, swing, awt

Java's default JFormattedTextField is not easy to use. What are the other Java libraries available that provide an advanced formatted text field?

Comment: "*Java's default JFormattedTextField is not easy to use*"..How so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSyntaxTextArea has served me well. I'm using it in the [jOOQ Console](http://www.jooq.org/manual/ADVANCED/ExecuteListener/):

http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/

Although, that might be a bit of overkill for you...?

Comment: +1 I use RSyntaxTextArea too and I'm quite happy with it. It's easy to use and has built-in syntax highlighting for many common formats.

Comment: I just need a simple formatted text field. not a text area. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use simple [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) and set a [`DocumentFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) filter on it. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8017847/597657).