# text field only accept numeric input

Tags: java, swing, jframe, document, jtextfield

I have a jframe with a text field. I want to ask how can only accept input text field containing numbers, so when users enter the letters will not be accepted

Comment: have a look into the tutorial referenced in the [swing tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) - it has more than one chapter dedicated to textfields and how-to achieve basic goals :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DocumentFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html): [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8017847/597657).

Also see:

- [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)
- [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)