# Detecting JTextField "deselect" event

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield, focuslistener

Is there some way to detect if a JTextField is deselected, i.e. the field WAS selected but now you have selected something else. The reason why I want to do this is because I want to check my users forms for any illegal characters before they try to submit their data. If there is some easier way to do that, instead of the way I'm trying to solve it, I'll gladly accept enlightenment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At first though use a [`FocusAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) and override `focusLost(FocusEvent fe)` which will be called when `JTextField` loses focuses, i.e another component is selected.

However because you have a purpose:

> I want to check my users forms for any illegal characters before they
>   try to submit their data

Id suggest a read on [How to Use the Focus Subsystem - Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)

Better options than a `FocusAdapter` - tailored made for validating/restricting user input:

- [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058505/jtextfield-accept-only-alphabet-and-white-space/14060047#14060047) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174776/how-to-auto-calculate-input-numeric-values-of-text-field-in-java/14174868#14174868) variation for an example.
- [`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11818946/1133011) for an example
- [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881301/best-way-to-constrain-user-to-enter-a-time-in-a-jtextfield/11881523#11881523) for an example