# Validate textfield input in GUI

Tags: java, validation, user-interface

I have two text fields and they must add up to 100 when submit is clicked, if I put in correct values into text field there's no error but if I leave the text field blank or put a letter in it the error handling isn't right. Any ideas?

```
submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (validation == true) {
            int numA = Integer.parseInt(aTextField.getText());
            int numB = Integer.parseInt(aTextField.getText());
            int sum = numA + numB;

            if (sum == 100) {
                validation = true;
                System.out.println("success");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(createFrame, "A and B must add up to 100");
                validation = false;

            }


        }
```

this is the error

```
int numA = Integer.parseInt(aTextField.getText());
```

Comment: You must check the values before converting it. Or use something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319064/how-to-validate-a-jtextfield-to-accept-only-interger-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt(str);` throws a `NumberFormatException` (the error you are seeing) if the `String` parsed into the method can not be converted into a number.

You could use some exception handling in this particular situation. I would suggest a `try` and `catch` block. For example;

```
   try{
       if(validation == true){
            int numA = Integer.parseInt(aTextField.getText());
            int numB = Integer.parseInt(aTextField.getText());
            int sum = numA + numB;

            if(sum == 100){
                validation = true;
                System.out.println("success");
            } else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(createFrame, "A and B must add up to 100");
                validation = false;
            }
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException n){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(createFrame, "Only numbers should be entered into A and B");
            validation = false;
    }
```

If the exception is now thrown from within the `try` block, it will be 'caught' and then validation will be set to `false` in the `catch` block. You could also use the catch block to display a message saying that only numbers should be entered into the fields.

Another way to achieve this using the Swing API is if you don't want them to **ever** put texts into those fields you could use a [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) to allow them to only enter numbers.

I hope this helps. Let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [javadoc of Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)! The function cannot handle an empty string. What number should that be anyways?

Possible solutions:

- set the default text of your textFields to "0"
- add exception handling for the parseInt calls (you could fall back to
  0 or prompt the user to correct)