# How to make a coordinate format for JTextField in java

Tags: java

> latitude: 43,324523 longitude: 34,958140

I used IntegerField provided here [IntegerField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319064/how-to-validate-a-jtextfield-to-accept-only-integer-numbers)

I can parse the number to get the format what I like but I want it while in the frame screen. When user typing (without entering dot or comma)

But how I will be able to make it.

this is the frame I would like to edit

[In this screen it should be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9hLt.png)

[Like the second box, User won't enter the dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pVku.png) but this is not the format I like. When you read the code you will understand what I mean.

third screenshot was shot with this code

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("##,####");
format.setGroupingUsed(true);
NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
formatter.setValueClass(Integer.class);                  
formatter.setMaximum(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);

IntegerField minField = new IntegerField();
JFormattedTextField maxField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found solution. MaskFormatter deals with this problem very well. Still, any other ideas would be appreciated

```
MaskFormatter latitudeformat=new MaskFormatter("##.######");
MaskFormatter longitudeformat=new MaskFormatter("###.######");
latitudeformat.setPlaceholderCharacter('0');
latitudeformat.setOverwriteMode(true);
longitudeformat.setPlaceholderCharacter('0');
longitudeformat.setOverwriteMode(true);    

JFormattedTextField latitudeField = new JFormattedTextField(latitudeformat);
JFormattedTextField longituteField = new JFormattedTextField(longitudeformat);
```

Comment: Longitude goes from -180 degrees to +180 degrees.  You've only allotted 2 digits.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yeah i know just copy pasted. but it is only the way workaround I found. also with this method I can't add write negative numbers.. 
Edited the answer.
Btw sir do you know how to improve this answer to be really able to insert latitude and longitude in the extent of -90 to +90 and -180 to +180

Comment: MaskFormatter is not designed for general double input.  There's no mask character for + and - that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

latitudes and longitudes are not integer values i guess ;)
use just two labled JTextFields one for longitudes and the other for latitudes

integers values are basically Strings of numbers from 0 to 9 and the minus 
to make floats you only need to accept the '.'

Comment: but I want to make user could only enter number. so i used jformattedtextfield.

Comment: that's exactly what a text field is for =], a formatted text field is used when you have data that has a format like a date or time but to read a numeric value JTextField is more appropriate; all you have to do is this txtField1 = new JTextField(10 );   
double value = Double.parseDouble(txtField1.getText());

Comment: See [how to validate a jtextfield to accept only integer numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319064/how-to-validate-a-jtextfield-to-accept-only-integer-numbers)

Comment: No you got me wrong. In frame i want to permit the user to enter any string to the field. In your way user can enter a string.

Comment: @NicoT will try that but the question is formatting rather than accepting only integers :D

Comment: Edited the question now my question should be clear :)

Answer (score 0):

The GUI would contain 2 JLabels and 2 JTextFields, arranged like your example.

```
Latitude: 43,324523    Longitude: 34,958140
```

You would test for doubles in the JTextFields with the following code:

```
public double convertTextToDouble(String text) {
    try {
        return Double.valueOf(text);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return Double.MIN_VALUE;
    }
}
```

If the text is a valid double, you'll return the double value.  If the text is not a valid double, you'll return the minimum double value.

Normally, you wouldn't use exceptions to test for invalid values.  In this case, you should because the exception already exists.

Comment: thanks for replying. but it is not what i want. I edit the post in order to be more clear. Sorry for the low skilled English.

Answer (score 0):

```
MaskFormatter latitudeformat=new MaskFormatter("*##.######");
**latitudeformat.setValidCharacters("-+1234567890");**
MaskFormatter longitudeformat=new MaskFormatter("*###.######");
**longitudeformat.setValidCharacters("-+1234567890");**
latitudeformat.setPlaceholderCharacter('0');
latitudeformat.setOverwriteMode(true);
longitudeformat.setPlaceholderCharacter('0');
longitudeformat.setOverwriteMode(true);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.

Comment: The Mask passed to the constructor *##.###### expects the first character to be any character while the rest to be digits. More information on the this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html.  We further restrict the character to be inputted by setting further the valid characters. hence the first letter can only take a value of +- or any digit