# JFormattedTextfield create mask with variable length

Tags: java, swing, formatter

Hello I'd like to use a mask for a `JFormattedTextField` this way:

```
MaskFormatter mask = new MaskFormatter("AA AAAA AAAA");
myField = new JFormattedTextField(mask);
```

but I want to be able to type variable number of characters, e.g.:

```
aa 11
4a 1125 4
```

etc.

Is there any simple way to do this, instead of extending `maskformatter` or writing my own class?

Thank u

Comment: You could try a [Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

Comment: +1 to Mads comment See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305921/detecting-jtextfield-deselect-event/14305952#14305952) answer with many other ways (including DocumentFilter) and their examples.