# Add leading zeros while using NumberFormat, JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield, number-formatting, jformattedtextfield

This is somewhat of an extension to this question: [Formatting JTextField to accept three digits at most, but anything up to 1-3 digits can be typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375432)

The following code allows me to enter value from 1-3 digits (ie. 1, 10, 100):

```
NumberFormat amountFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
amountFormat.setMinimumIntegerDigits(1);
amountFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits(3);
amountFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);

amountField = new JFormattedTextField(amountFormat);
```

What I would like is to add leading zeros if 1 or 2 digits are entered (ie. 1 or 01 => 001, 10 => 010).

Perhaps I can somehow use the string formatter?

```
String.format("%03d", num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, for example:

```
if (someString.matches("^\\d{1,2}$")) {
    String appendZero = "0"+someString
}
```

The if returns true if someString contains exactly two digits.

Comment: Doesn't the String's format function do all the checking for me?

Comment: if you simply want to padd with zeroes if at least 3 digits are not entered, then yes.
String.format("%03d", 1) = 001
String.format("%03d", 10) = 010
String.format("%03d", 1) = 100
String.format("%03d", 1011) = 1011
Test it - http://www.javarepl.com/console.html

Comment: My question is how do I incorporate the checking/formatting while using NumberFormat, JFormattedTextField?

Comment: You want to show the padded zeroes in the textfield as the user types in? Then you must have a listener (PropertyChangeListener) that captures the value while typing, padds the values and updates the textfield or some other label. The padding can be done by the String.format(). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I did not ask the question correctly, but the (simplest) answer to my current question would be to use the string format when displaying the given input (as suggested in the original post).