# Sub-Class of JTextField , that only Accepts Alphanumerical Value and . (dot)

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield, alphanumeric

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jTextField accept only alphabet and white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058505/jtextfield-accept-only-alphabet-and-white-space)

Ey!
i have a Custom `JTextField` (extends from `JTextField`) , this `CustomJTextField` ,mainly has the `JtextField` Methods in Spanish like `setFont` Renamed to `SetFuente`,

In this Custom `JTextField` ,i need to create a method that validates that the only values that can be written are Alphanumeric and (.) dot , so if i write (,) or (*) the symbol doesn't appear on the `JTextField`, something like `CustomJTextField.setFormat(ALPHA)`.

i didnt find the Swing library that can help me with this, any suggestion is weel received

thx!

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305921/detecting-jtextfield-deselect-event/14305952#14305952) similar question/answer. Which shows the various native java ways to verify/filter input to text components.

Comment: Also you can override replaceSelection method of JTextField, but the other options are better.

Comment: sry im new on forum and i had no idea about this components .im now tryng to use a DocumentFilter , that uses the characters from a Hashmap and only let me write the characters contained in the HashMap