# Alphabets validation of jtextfield

Tags: java, swing

I have been trying to just display the alphabets in the jtextfield.Even though the other keys are pressed the jtextfield should not display them only the alphabets are to be displayed.can you please help me with this..

Comment: Take a look at [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) and [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jTextField accept only alphabet and white space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058505/jtextfield-accept-only-alphabet-and-white-space)

Comment: but sir i dont need to display the other keys pressed in the jtextbox.

Comment: you just need to remove the condition for whitespace. thats it.

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a look at [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class TestFilter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFilter();
    }

    public TestFilter() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
                ((AbstractDocument)field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new CharFilter());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(field);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class CharFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        @Override
        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                        String string, AttributeSet attr)
                        throws BadLocationException {

            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(string);
            for (int i = buffer.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                char ch = buffer.charAt(i);
                if (!Character.isAlphabetic(ch)) {
                    buffer.deleteCharAt(i);
                }
            }
            super.insertString(fb, offset, buffer.toString(), attr);
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb,
                        int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            if (length > 0) {
                fb.remove(offset, length);
            }
            insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }
    }
}
```

You ma also find [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) helpful

Comment: Works fine for me, trade you a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem

Comment: Take the `CharFilter`, copy it to it's own class.  Modify your code to use it as demonstrated, `((AbstractDocument)field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new CharFilter());`...

Comment: This is an example of the concept of which you are going to have to integrate into your code, we're not going to do it for you...you can't afford our rates... ;)

Comment: Remember, effort will be rewarded ;)

Answer (score -1):

here is a solution if you want only alphabets to be entered to a jtextfield,and no other keys should be entered even though they get pressed.in your jframe just select your jtextfield rightclick on jtextfield you will find events and then go to events click on keyTyped event and then write the following code to enter only the alphabets into your jtextfield.

private void tfempidKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:

```
    char key = evt.getKeyChar();
    if (key > '0' && key < '9') {
        evt.consume();
    }
```

Comment: `KeyListener` is a poor choice for filtering content within text components, this is why the `DocumentFilter` API was created.  There is no guarantee in the order that `KeyListener`s are notified, meaning that the key stroke may already have been delivered to the text component's `Document` and under some circumstances if cause a document mutation exception to be generated.