# java how to delete the contents of JTextPane as user types?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, jtextpane, documentlistener

I want to delete the contents of my `JTextPane` as the user types, I mean

```
JTextPane.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter()
{
   public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
   {
      searchFieldHandler(evt);
   }
});

private void searchFieldHandler(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
{        
   text = searchField.getText() + String.valueOf(evt.getKeyChar());
   **searchField.setText("");**

   // doing sth with text
}
```

but it doesn't work(doesn't delete the contents and the last entered char remains) how to do that?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) if you want to do some actions after the user typed into the textPane, and use [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) if you want to filter the input before it appears on the textPane.

**See:**

- [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)
- [Only allowing numbers and a symbol (-) to be typed into a JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8017847/597657)

Comment: +1 See also [*Implementing a Document Filter*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)