# Make JFormattedTextField accept decimal with more than 3 digits

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I have a `JFormattedTextField` that should be able to accept double numbers with more than 3 decimal digits. It accepts entries `0.1`, `0.01`, `0.001` but rejects `0.0001` and numbers with more decimal digits.

This is how my code works now:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.0E0");
JFormattedTextField txtfield = new JFormattedTextField(decimalFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.getDefault()));
```

How do I get my text field to accept numbers with more than 3 decimal digits?

Comment: This is not an answer, but alternative http://stackoverflow.com/a/8017847/597657

Comment: Seems like a job for `DocumentFilter` see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305921/detecting-jtextfield-deselect-event/14305952#14305952) for an example of `DocumentFilter` and other ways and their respective examples. You can have variable lengthed mask but thats too much IMO but incase you want to see it [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1363095).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It accepts entries 0.1, 0.01, 0.001 but rejects 0.0001 and numbers
>   with more decimal digits.

this should be settable in  [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) / [DecimalFormat (in your case)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) by `setMinimumFractionDigits(int)`, `setMaximumFractionDigits(int)` and /or with `setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.Xxx)`, more in [Oracle tutorial about Formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/index.html)

for example

```
final JFormattedTextField textField1 = new JFormattedTextField(new Float(10.01));
    textField1.setFormatterFactory(new AbstractFormatterFactory() {

        @Override
        public AbstractFormatter getFormatter(JFormattedTextField tf) {
            NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
            format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            InternationalFormatter formatter = new InternationalFormatter(format);
            formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
            formatter.setMinimum(0.0);
            formatter.setMaximum(1000.00);
            return formatter;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @both, but there all advantage of JFormattedTextField ended, (-: the best for un_editable fields and only for nicer formatting :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. Nice solution =)

If I enter ```0.0000000001``` for instance, after allowing 12 fraction digits, how do I get it to show this as ```1.0e-9```?

Comment: there is possible to add InputMask (code example in my answer), see Scientific Notation in  DecimalFormats API