# JFormattedTextfield with any number of fraction digits

Tags: java

How to create a JFormattedTextField which can accept any number of fractional digits in a decimal number?

```
 JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField();
      tf
      .setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(
          new javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter(new java.text.DecimalFormat())));
```

This accepts only 3 fractional digits since maximum  fraction digits is 3 by default for DecimalFormat.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits%28int%29

Comment: may be this will help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876695/make-jformattedtextfield-accept-decimal-with-more-than-3-digits

Comment: It asks to set maximum fraction digits. But in my case i dont know the maximum fraction digits

Answer (score 0):

This will set the number of fractional digits to a maximum:

```
JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField();
DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
tf.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(
    new javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter(df)));
```

Please note that this does not mean "any number" as in your question. As specified in [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits(int)) of `setMaximumFractionDigits`:

> The concrete subclass may enforce an upper limit to this value
>   appropriate to the numeric type being formatted.

this doesn't matter in your example, but

> For formatting numbers other than BigInteger and BigDecimal objects,
>   the lower of newValue and 340 is used. Negative input values are
>   replaced with 0.

But I guess this should be enough for most cases.